# IIS URL Redirect works, but Rewrite throws 403 forbidden error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a web.config file in a subdirectory of an IIS application like this

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>         
          <rules>
            <rule name="Proxy2" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"  ignoreCase="true"/>
                    <conditions>
                      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*" />
                  </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://anotherurl.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule> 
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

so, if I browse https://www.abc.com/subdir , it will return 403 forbidden error. but if I change the action to redirect, it will redirect without problems. what should I look for to find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to rewrite to another URL (or another Application Pool). Only redirect will work in this case.

Edit: Technically it's *possible*, but not the way you've implemented it. If you want to rewrite to another URL, you'll need to implement as a reverse proxy using the [Application Request Routing (ARR)](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) module in IIS.